# size of class containg virtual member functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am new to C++ programming, i have doubt regarding size of class containing virtual member functions. please go through my below code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BaseClass
{
private:
    int a, b;
public:
    BaseClass()
    {
        a = 10;
        b = 20;
    }

    virtual int area()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

class DerivedClass1 : public BaseClass
{
    int x;

public:
    virtual void simple()
    {
        cout << "inside simple" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedClass1 Obj;
    cout << sizeof(Obj) << endl; // Displays 16 bytes

    return 0;
}
```

The above code showing size as 16 bytes. according to me it should show 20 bytes because two virtual pointers(one is inherited from base class and one is added to derived class itself because of virtual function of it's own)  + three data members in Derived Class is equal to 20 bytes. so please explain me how it is ....

Comment: Inheriting the virtual pointer _and_ adding another one? Why would that happen?

Comment: read about [virtual table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Comment: Additional vptrs only come into the picture if you have multiple inheritance. Also, the result of your experiment is very much compiler and platform dependent; when [compiled with g++](http://liveworkspace.org/code/10xj5R$10) it outputs 24, as does VS2012 when building a 64-bit executable.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, Because Virtual table pointer will be common across the class hierarchy. So, BaseClass already have virtual function, the additional virtual function at DeriveClass1 won't add anything to the size of the class.

This is the memory layout of your class:

```
class DerivedClass1 size(16):
    +---
    | +--- (base class BaseClass)
 0  | | {vfptr}
 4  | | a
 8  | | b
    | +---
12  | x
    +---

Derivedass1::$vftable@:
    | &DerivedClass1_meta
    |  0
 0  | &BaseClass::area
 1  | &DerivedClass1::simple
```

You can use -d1reportAllClassLayout option when compile in MVSC to show the memory layout of class.

Comment: Isn't there a possibility of the derived class function being bigger?

Comment: When BaseClass doesn't have any virtual function, but at DeriveClass has one or more virtual function. In this case, we will have a vfptr ( 4bytes) more in DerivedClass compared with BaseClass ( does not have vfptr).